# $(\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_6)/\langle(2,3)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_6$ or $\mathbb Z_{12}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

$(\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_6)/\langle(2,3)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_6$ or $\mathbb Z_{12}$ ?

I think $(\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_6)/\langle(2,3)\rangle$ is **not**
cyclic group but $\mathbb Z_{12}$  is cyclic.

I cannot construct a homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_6\to\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_6$ such that $\ker\phi=\langle(2,3)\rangle$.

Comment: How about  $(x,y) \mapsto (2x, 2y)$?

Comment: @Derek That doesn't quite work; for your homomorphism, $\ker\phi = \langle (2,0),(0,3)\rangle$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ah right, good catch.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815737/find-the-homomorphism-corresponding-to-mathbb-z-4-times-mathbb-z-6-langle2?rq=1

Comment: @DerekAllums . I can't find relation between $\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_6$

Comment: One group has an element of order $4$.  The other does not.